# классы навигационного меню wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Фнкция wp_nav_menu() генерирует следующую структуру:

```
<ul id="" class="">
  <li id="" class=""><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

Вопрос такой, как удалить стандартные классы и id у элементов списка li и добавить свои классы этим li и тегу a внутри него.

Вычитал, что можно через объект `Walker`

```
class mainMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
 function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
// назначаем классы li-элементу и выводим его
$class_names = ' class="main-menu_item"'; 
$output.= '<li' .$class_names. '>';

// назначаем атрибуты a-элементу
$attributes.= !empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' .esc_attr($item->url). '" class="main-menu_link"  ' : '';
$item_output = $args->before;

// проверяем, на какой странице мы находимся
$current_url = (is_ssl()?'https://':'http://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$item_url = esc_attr( $item->url );
$item_output.= '<a'. $attributes .'>'.$item->title.'</a>';


// заканчиваем вывод элемента
$item_output.= $args->after;
$output.= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output,     $item, $depth, $args );
  }
}
```

В данном примере классы тупо вшиты, что и пойдет если на сайте одно меню, но как быть если их 2 допустим и оформление разное... Как можно передавать название классов параметром? Туговато у меня с php пока, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: непонятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Какой список, где, откуда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть функция wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu ). Пример использования:

```
$menu_name = 'custom_menu_slug';

if( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() && isset($locations[ $menu_name ]) ){
  $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] ); // получаем ID

  $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu ); // получаем элементы меню

  // создаем список
  $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '">';

  foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ){
    $menu_list .= '<li><a href="' . $menu_item->url . '">' . $menu_item->title . '</a></li>';
  }

  $menu_list .= '</ul>';
  }
  else 
  $menu_list = '<ul><li>Меню "' . $menu_name . '" не определено.</li></ul>';
```