# Walker_Nav_menu Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

И так, продолжаю эксперименты с **Walker_Nav_menu Wordpress**.
Ранее я уже создавал темы касательно модификации этого класса:
[Ошибка: Warning: Illegal string offset](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613262/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-warning-illegal-string-offset/613278#613278)
[классы навигационного меню wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568792/%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-wordpress)
Наконец я добился искомых результатов и получился следующий код:

```
class mainMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    /**
    *   аргументы - массив с ключами:
    *   'item_class' - класс элемента <li>
    *   'child_menu_class' - класс дочернего меню (вложенного <ul>)
    *   'parent_item_class' - класс родительского элемента <li>
    *   'current_item_class' - текущий пункт меню
    *   'link_class' - класс ссылки
    **/
    private $items = array();
    public function __construct($arg = array()){
        if(!empty($arg) && (is_array($arg) || is_object($arg))) {
            $this->arg = $arg;
        }
    }
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        if(!isset($this->classes['child_menu_class'])) {
                $class = (!empty($this->arg['child_menu_class'])) ? $this->arg['child_menu_class'] : 'sub_menu';
            }
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"{$class}\">\n";
    }
    public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        // создается массив в котором будут CSS классы темы. 
        // массив имеет 2 ключа 'li' и 'a', которые в свою очередь также массивы с CSS классами для li и a элементов меню. 
        if(empty($item->theme_classes)) {
            $item->theme_classes = array('li' => array(), 'a' => array());
        }
        // заполнение 'li' массива:
        // не придумал ничего умнее, чем посмотреть есть ли стандартный CSS клас добавляемый родительскому пункту меню.
        // при наличии заполняется массив с CSS классами темы, созданный ранее, необходимым ключом с нужным значением.
        if(is_array($item->classes)) {
            foreach($item->classes as $key => $value) {
                if(is_string($value) && $value === 'menu-item-has-children') {
                    $item->theme_classes['li'][] = (!empty($this->arg['parent_item_class'])) ? $this->arg['parent_item_class'] : 'menu_item--parrent';
                }
            }
        }
        // продолжаем заполнять массив
        $item->theme_classes['li'][] = (!empty($this->arg['item_class'])) ? $this->arg['item_class'] : 'menu_item';

        // заполнение 'a' массивa:
        $item->theme_classes['a'][] = (!empty($this->arg['link_class'])) ? $this->arg['link_class'] : 'menu_link';

        if($item->current) {
            $item->theme_classes['a'][] = (!empty($this->arg['current_item_class'])) ? $this->arg['current_item_class'] : 'menu_item--current'; // класс a элемента текущего пункта меню 
        }

        // генерация CSS классов 'li' элементов
        $classes = empty( $item->theme_classes['li'] ) ? array() : (array) $item->theme_classes['li'];
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li'. $class_names .'>';

        // генерация CSS классов 'a' элементов
        $classes = empty( $item->theme_classes['a'] ) ? array() : (array) $item->theme_classes['a'];
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );

        // атрибуты элемента, title="", rel="", target="", href="", class="" 
        $atts = array();
        $atts['class']  = ! empty( $class_names )      ? $class_names      : '';
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        // ссылка и околоссылочный текст
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Используется следующим образом:

```
<?php $main_menu = new mainMenuWalker (
         array(
            'parent_item_class' => 'nav_item--parent',
            'child_menu_class' => 'my_sub_class',
            'item_class' => 'nav__item phg',
            'link_class' => 'nav__link',
            'current_item_class' => 'nav_link--active'
         )
       ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                     'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
                     'container' => '',
                     'menu_class' => 'nav-menu-hidden',
                     'menu_id' => 'navMenu',
                      'walker' => $main_menu
                  )); ?>
```

И все хорошо, работает так как и планировалось, но есть одно **НО**, когда в файле конфигураций `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, вылазиет вот такое чудо:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of mainMenuWalker::start_el() should be
>   compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0,
>   $args = Array, $id = 0) in
>   F:\OpenServer\domains\racing.loc\wp-content\themes\racing\functions.php
>   on line 286

**Как победить?**
**P.S.**
Очень прошу знатоков php и wordpress взглянуть на данное творение и указать на ошибки.

*Один из промежуточных рабочих вариантов (в планах доработать, но руки не доходят)*

```html
/**
*переопределение классов меню
**/
class mainMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
 /**
 * аргументы - массив с ключами:
 * 'item_class' - класс элемента <li>
 * 'child_menu_class' - класс дочернего меню (вложенного <ul>)
 * 'parent_item_class' - класс родительского элемента <li>
 * 'current_item_class' - текущий пункт меню
 * 'link_class' - класс ссылки
 **/
 private $items = array();
 public function __construct($arg = array()){
  if(!empty($arg) && (is_array($arg) || is_object($arg))) {
   $this->arg = $arg;
  }
 }
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
  $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
  if(!isset($this->classes['child_menu_class'])) {
    $class = (!empty($this->arg['child_menu_class'])) ? $this->arg['child_menu_class'] : 'sub_menu';
   }
  $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"{$class}\">\n";
 }
 public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
  $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
  // создается массив в котором будут CSS классы темы. 
  // массив имеет 2 ключа 'li' и 'a', которые в свою очередь также массивы с CSS классами для li и a элементов меню. 
  if(empty($item->theme_classes)) {
   $item->theme_classes = array('li' => array(), 'a' => array());
  }
  // заполнение 'li' массива:
  // не придумал ничего умнее, чем посмотреть есть ли стандартный CSS клас добавляемый родительскому пункту меню.
  // при наличии заполняется массив с CSS классами темы, созданный ранее, необходимым ключом с нужным значением.
  if(is_array($item->classes)) {
   foreach($item->classes as $key => $value) {
    if(is_string($value) && $value === 'menu-item-has-children') {
     $item->theme_classes['li'][] = (!empty($this->arg['parent_item_class'])) ? $this->arg['parent_item_class'] : 'menu_item--parrent';
    }
   }
  }
  // продолжаем заполнять массив
  $item->theme_classes['li'][] = (!empty($this->arg['item_class'])) ? $this->arg['item_class'] : 'menu_item';
  
  // заполнение 'a' массивa:
  $item->theme_classes['a'][] = (!empty($this->arg['link_class'])) ? $this->arg['link_class'] : 'menu_link';
  
  if($item->current) {
   $item->theme_classes['a'][] = (!empty($this->arg['current_item_class'])) ? $this->arg['current_item_class'] : 'menu_item--current'; // класс a элемента текущего пункта меню 
  }

  // генерация CSS классов 'li' элементов
  $classes = empty( $item->theme_classes['li'] ) ? array() : (array) $item->theme_classes['li'];
  $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
  $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

  $output .= $indent . '<li'. $class_names .'>';

  // генерация CSS классов 'a' элементов
  $classes = empty( $item->theme_classes['a'] ) ? array() : (array) $item->theme_classes['a'];
  $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );

  // атрибуты элемента, title="", rel="", target="", href="", class="" 
  $atts = array();
  $atts['class']  = ! empty( $class_names )     ? $class_names      : '';
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

  // ссылка и околоссылочный текст
  $item_output = $args->before;
  $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
  $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
  $item_output .= '</a>';
  $item_output .= $args->after;
 
   $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас 4 аргумента, а класс требует 5.

Comment: @KAGG Design, Вот спасибо добрый человек

Comment: :) пожалуйста...

Comment: Добрый день, а можете поделиться исправленной версией?

Comment: @Aleksandr, обновил, я не жадный :)